# Render a template inside an attribute

Tags: templates, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a template which I am trying to render in a bootstrap popover but when I do the code below it just renders `[object Object]`. Is it possible to make it render the complete template somehow?

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" title="sometitle" data-bind="attr: { 'data-content': { template: { name: 'a-template', data: somedata} } }"></a>
```

Thanks for your sage advice and better wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, render template in computed field and assign that field to that data-content attribute. See below:

Specify your template

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
        // Some HTML here
</script>
```

Generate a computed field based on template specified above.

```
<script>
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.templateField= ko.computed(function(){
        var temp = $("<div>");
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(temp[0], { template: { name: 'templateName', data: self } });
        var html = temp.html();
        temp.remove();
        return html;
    }, self);
}
</script>
```

And now use computed field created above in attribute.

```
<anyElement data-bind="attr: {'data-content': templateField}"/>
```

Comment: I wrote my own helper for this but this answer probably works fine so I accepted it. :) Thanks anyway.